# Replace view with angularJS

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

I'm building an ionic app. The app has about 30 views. some of them are locked and to user isn't able to interact on them with a reason. If the user scanns a barcode the about 10 Views should be replaced with other content. It's not very much. It should be consistent after the scan. So a relaunch will show the unlocked content. Do I have to do this with CSS and hide/show, or is there a nicer solution for this?

Comment: I would suggest using localstorage. Like take a boolean flag like isScanned = false and check it whenever the app is opened 1st and navigate accordingly

Comment: Yeah, that is it. Thank you very much! Do you think it's fast enough?

Comment: Yes i think its fast enough

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If i would have to do this in ionic and angularJs.

I would have maintained an object or array of items/states that can be accesses.

Whenever i have to allow a user to access a state i would have added that state to allowed array/object so that it can be accessed.

Now if on same page i have to show content based on permissions i would have done something like below

```
<div ng-if="state | permissions ">
```

and my array would have been something like

```
var permissions = {
   'all'  :{'state':['home']},
   'user' :{'state':['home','question'},
   'admin':{'state':['home','admin','users']}
```

and filter could look like

```
.filter('permissions',function(){
   return function(role){
       return permissions[role].state 
      // implement contains functionality
   }
});
```

Comment: Thank you! But the user has always the premission to view a view, but isn't able to interact there. he only can scan the qr code there.

Comment: then you can change implemention  for view and actions to be performed